# NPN trigger voltage & resistor temperature

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to trigger the base directly. What must be the voltage needed? This is the datasheet.

http://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/SSMPTransistor/SOT-23/MMBTA44.pdf

Can I just use DC and separate power supply to trigger it. I don't want any AC if possible.

[image]

Also when the base triggered it and Collector has current flowing to Emitter.

How hot do you think can the 1M ohm resistor get (estimate) when it is continuously exposed to 240v ac supply?

Comment: "trigger" is a word usually seen in reference to SCRs, not BJTs. A BJT will turn on as long as its base-emitter junction is forward-biased (about 0.6~0.7 volts for silicon BJTs)

Comment: for 240v, it's so hard to add resistor make it merely 0.6~0.7v that is why I' was thinking if a separate DC could be used to make base-emitter forward biased.

Comment: If you're talking about 240VAC, be aware that transistors don't work on AC. Or at least they don't work the same way they do on DC.

Comment: Your design does not work. Start by including your spec tolerances for input and output

Comment: I can't even tell if it works, or doesn't, because I've zero idea what you want to achieve. Can you attempt a complete re-write and tell us more about the circumstances, context, and goals?

Comment: I just want to turn on the collection/emitter link to see what would happen to the circuit. If 50v is applied to the base-emitter forward biased instead of just 0.6-0.7v, would the current from collector flows to emitter? Just tell me what resistor to add to turn it on. This is all i'm asking here. Thanks.